How should I calculate a pseudo R-squared for models with a quasi-binomial distribution?
I have created a model in R using the glm function with family = quasibinomial. I am trying to calculate the psquedo R-squared, the cox-snell variant, to compare with an existing study.
However, as the cox-snell R-squared uses log likelihoods, how would I adjust it for a model with a quasi distribution?

It might make sense to divide the log-likelihoods by the overdispersion factor (i.e. sum(pearson_resids^2)/residual_df), but that's just a guess.

What do you want it to tell you?

I want to compare the r-squared to an existing study, so I can see if my model explains as much as the variance as theirs

Pseudo $R^2$ statistics in generalized linear models do not generally address explained variance proportion, really only OLS linear regression (with an intercept, when calculated in-sample). Thus, you are chasing something that does not exist. With that in mind, their Cox-Snell pseudo $R^2$ is a form of comparing model likelihood with the likelihood of a benchmark. Now that you have fit your model, it seems like you can use your model to make predictions and stick those predictions into the likelihood functions required for the Cox-Snell pseudo $R^2$. Is this not feasible in your situation?
